# Book 2 of Visual Complex Functions

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, visualization

I am having a lot of fun in reading [Visual Complex Functions](http://www.visual.wegert.com/) by Professor Wegert. (It is a very interesting read and well-recommended by me.)

Inside it, he regularly lets things be and postpones until part 2 or book 2. I have asked Professor Wegert himself about his plans with it (or a title), but unfortunately he seems to be busy at the moment.

That's why I am asking the community: Does anyone know of the book 2 mentioned in Visual Complex Functions, or when it is due ?

Comment: In the meantime, check out the author's calendars at https://tu-freiberg.de/en/fakult1/ana/institute/institute-of-applied-analysis/organisation/complex-beauties

Answer (score 3):

In personal correspondence with the author back in 2018, he said that the plan still exists for a second volume, but he cannot say when it will appear.

I am looking forward to any news too. If I hear anything, I will try to remember to post an update here.